# Is there a simplified form of this expression?

Tags: probability

I have the following expression:
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{K} \left(p_k \prod_{n=1}^{k-1}(1-p_n)\right)
$$
All the $p_k$ are between 0 and 1.

From numerical evaluations, I can see that when the $p_k$ are small, $S$ tends closer to zero, and when the $p_k$ are close to 1, $S$ tends closer to 1.

I wanted to see if the experts here can come up with a simplification of $S$ as a function of the $p_k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_k=\prod_{n=1}^k(1-p_n)$. Then

$$p_k\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}(1-p_n)=p_kS_{k-1}=\bigl(1-(1-p_k)\bigr)S_{k-1}=S_{k-1}-(1-p_k)S_{k-1}=S_{k-1}-S_k\,.$$

Therefore $S=\sum_{k=1}^K(S_{k-1}-S_k)$ telescopes to $S_0-S_K=1-\prod_{n=1}^K(1-p_k)$.

Comment: Nice solution +1. I do not understand why $S_0=1$ though?

Comment: @Stefanos $S_0=1$ by convention: note that we have $\prod_{n=1}^ka_n=a_k\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}a_n$ whenever $k\geq2$ for any $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Defining $\prod_{n=1}^0a_n$ as $1$ makes the equality also true for $k=1$.